# How to dynamically add SuperScript to number in ASP.NET/C# ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to add `SuperScript` to number in `C#`.

Example:

```
1st, 2nd ......
```

This i want to do dynamically in `ASP.NET/C#`

Please suggest best possible solution.

Comment: @Abhishek What have you tried so far?Post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `<sup>` tag is the correct way to markup these values.

> this i want to do dynamically in asp.net c#

If you have some knowledge of the locale, you could automatically add `<sup>` tags to text.

### Matching

```
// this should go in a helper class

// Obviously this depends on locale. The regex can be altered to accept numbers
// with as many digits as desired. I think "th" is always an appropriate suffix
// in English (not sure).
private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex( @"^(\d{1,8})(st|nd|rd|th)$", RegexOptions.Compiled );

public static string AddSuper( string value ) {
    return _regex.Replace( value, "$1<sup>$2</sup>" );
}
```

### Usage

```
// in code-behind
this.litMyText.Text = AddSuper( "1st" );

// a few test cases (also demonstrates processing multiple items)

// should match
var testValues = new[] { "1st", "2nd", "10th", "20th", "1000th", "3rd", "19th" };

foreach( string val in testValues ) {
    Response.Write( AddSuper( val ) );
}

// should not match
testValues = new[] { "test", "nd", "fourth", "25", "hello world th", "15,things", "1 1 1thousand" };

foreach( string val in testValues ) {
    Response.Write( AddSuper( val ) );
}
```

### Output on Matched Values

```
1<sup>st</sup>
2<sup>nd</sup>
10<sup>th</sup>
20<sup>th</sup>
1000<sup>th</sup>
3<sup>rd</sup>
19<sup>th</sup>
```

Comment: +1 for that.Great answer.I just hope it makes sense to the author.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on a functional example.

Answer (score 5):

I am not very sure what exactly you want.

You can do something like this though.

Let say you have a ASP.NET Label

```
<asp:Label ID="sample" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Then in the code behind you can do something like this

```
sample.Text=string.Format("1<sup>st</sup>");
```

This will output as 1<sup>st</sup>

Comment: What's the point of `string.Format` in your second code sample?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<sup>` tag:

```
1<sup>st</sup> 2<sup>nd</sup>, ...
```

will render as: 1<sup>st</sup> 2<sup>nd</sup>, ...

Comment: The OP asked for a way of doing this dynamically..

Comment: And what does this mean?

Comment: Doing it in the code-behind? He even explicitly said, "this i want to do dynamically in asp.net c#." I think he might want a way to change all numbers in a text so that they display this, though I'm not sure, the question isn't very clear..